# Python Summing Values and Gathering Unique Values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary named `blob` like so :

```
{
"/var/log": {"vgsize": "46.27g","vgname": "VolGroup","desired_lv_size": "20"},
"/opt": {"vgsize": "9.32g","vgname": "VolGroupOpt","desired_lv_size": "50"}
"/tmp": {"vgsize": "46.27g","vgname": "VolGroup","desired_lv_size": "20"}
}
```

I need to: get the sum of `desired_lv_size` for each `vgname`.

How would I approach this challenge?

I started with trying:

```
set(blob.values())
```

to possibly extract the unique `vgname`s. But that gave me:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: There's a missing quote in your code

Comment: you mean we have to skip the sub-dicts which are exactly identical right?

Comment: The answers below have interpreted your question differently. What is the output you expect for that input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for v in data.values():
    c[v['vgname']] += int(v["desired_lv_size"])
```

Comment: You can use dict with setdefault, also you can use defaultdict from collections module, but the best solution is Counter. Counter makes your code simpler and reduces lines of code.

Comment: what I don't understand here is why OP wanted to make a `set` to eliminate the duplicate dictionaries. Your answer ignores that completely, and though it gets 4 upvotes and acceptance. I must admit I'm lost here.

Comment: because topic starter sometimes doesn't know what he wants. But we should end chatting because it's not related with topic :)

Comment: you answer is good, but answers something that is only in the OP mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = {
    "/var/log": {"vgsize": "46.27g","vgname": "VolGroup","desired_lv_size": "20"},
    "/opt": {"vgsize": "9.32g","vgname": "VolGroupOpt","desired_lv_size": "50"},
    "/tmp": {"vgsize": "46.27g","vgname": "VolGroup","desired_lv_size": "20"}
}

res = defaultdict(int)
for d in data.values():
    group = d.get("vgname")
    value = float(d.get("desired_lv_size"))
    res[group] += value

print(res)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'VolGroup': 40.0, 'VolGroupOpt': 50.0})
```

Comment: And now add up the VolGroup!

Comment: Right, I missed that part. Update in a moment.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the 
desired_lv_size values are integers, this will work:

```
x={
"/var/log": {"vgsize": "46.27g","vgname": "VolGroup","desired_lv_size": "20"},
"/opt": {"vgsize": "9.32g","vgname": "VolGroupOpt","desired_lv_size": "50"},
"/tmp": {"vgsize": "46.27g","vgname": "VolGroup","desired_lv_size": "20"}
}

totals={}
for f, f_data in x.items():
    v=int(f_data["desired_lv_size"])
    if f_data["vgname"] in totals:
        totals[f_data["vgname"]]+=v
    else:
        totals[f_data["vgname"]]=v

for vgname, total in totals.items():
    print("{0} total={1}".format(vgname, total))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd iterate through the dictionary's values and add the `desired_lv_size` entries to a dictionary keyed by each `vgname`, like so:

```
vg_sizes = {}
for vg_dict in blob.values():
    size = vg_sizes.setdefault(vg_dict['vgname'], 0)
    vg_sizes[vg_dict['vgname']] = size + int(vg_dict['desired_lv_size'])
```

`vg_sizes` ends up as a dictionary keyed by all `'vgname'`s with value the sum of all the `'desired_lv_size'`s.

Comment: setdefault is not bad, but Counter is better because Counter reduces code and simplify it

Comment: I don't disagree :-)

Comment: So, don't confuse newbies ;)

Comment: But it's useful to be aware of both, so not a bad thing having both answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
blob = {
"/var/log": {"vgsize": "46.27g","vgname": "VolGroup","desired_lv_size": "20"},
"/opt": {"vgsize": "9.32g","vgname": "VolGroupOpt","desired_lv_size": "50"},
"/tmp": {"vgsize": "46.27g","vgname": "VolGroup","desired_lv_size": "20"}
}
a = {}
for value in blob.values():
    if value["vgname"] in a:
        a[value["vgname"]] += int(value["desired_lv_size"])
    else:
        a[value["vgname"]] = int(value["desired_lv_size"])
```

`a` is the required dict.

This approach just uses one more dict to store the final result, no extra imports and no complications.